# is there a way to make a bot say the name of who joined a vc with text to speech?

Tags: discord.py

how could this be done? I'm trying to make a bot that says the names of people who join a voice chat (usually a lot of people are in vc) so I wouldn't have to check/ask.

Comment: You want to make it say it with audio? Or printed or sent?

Comment: I wanna make it with audio.

Comment: Audio in the VC or on your PC?

Comment: Audio in the VC

Comment: What have you attempted in doing this? The docs give clear examples of this. You can implement the tts library with the voice_clients of discordpy to do this.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't really try anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bot that does this [KITT Bot](https://top.gg/bot/530825629793517590)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).